# Assembly: Break an infinite loop

Tags: assembly, x86-16

In this code, the program keeps getting stuck at the loop L2-L3. I want it to break the loop and go to L4 when the user presses a key. How to do it? Thanks!

I'm using emu8086.

```
L1: mov bl, 0
L2: cmp bl, 0
L3: je L2
L4: ...
```

Comment: That depends on your OS.

Comment: That's totally dependent on your hardware and OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to insert the appropriate (for system) code to check for a waiting keystroke.  DOS/x86 BIOS support various methods for doing so if you can target any of those.  Or, you can make in interrupt handler and use a variable as a trigger (using a register won't work in that case).